# Aliases are reset before every separate test file in Cypress

Tags: automation, cypress

I am running two tests separately. One is Signup Test File and otherone is Login. When I sign up I stored the data and wants to use it in Login Test File.
Signup Test file runs and showing alliases is created and values are stored but when I run the login Test file it shows me an error message of

> `cy.get()` could not find a registered alias for: @signupData.
>
> You have not aliased anything yet.

I run my Test file of login by getting data from sign up but its not working.

**SignUp Test File**

```
//import cypress from "cypress"
import { BrandSignUp } from "../Brand/brand_signup"

const signuppage = new BrandSignUp()

it('Brand Sign Up', () => {

cy.visit('https://staging:ec2-18-189-16-96.us-east-2@staging.brand.plastk.ca/sign-up', { failOnStatusCode: false })

const fakeEmail = signuppage.generateFakeEmail();
const fakePassword = signuppage.generateFakePassword();

signuppage.enterEmail(fakeEmail);
signuppage.enterPassword(fakePassword);
signuppage.enterConfirmPassword(fakePassword);
signuppage.checkTermsAndConditions();
signuppage.clickPasswordEyeIcon();
signuppage.clickConfirmPasswordEyeIcon();
signuppage.checkPasswordsMatch();
signuppage.clickSignUp();

cy.wrap({ fakeEmail, fakePassword }).as('signupData');

// signuppage.storeGeneratedEmail(fakeEmail);
// signuppage.storeGeneratedPassword(fakePassword);

})
```

**Login Test File**

```
//import cypress from "cypress"
import { BrandLogin } from "../Brand/brand_login"

const loginpage = new BrandLogin()

it('Login to Brand Portal', () => {

cy.visit('https://staging:ec2-18-189-16-96.us-east-2@staging.brand.plastk.ca/')

cy.get('@signupData').then((signupData) => {
    const { email, password } = signupData;

    // const SuEmail = loginpage.retrieveStoredEmail();
    // const SuPassword = loginpage.retrieveStoredPassword();

    loginpage.enterEmail(email);
    loginpage.enterPassword(password);
    loginpage.enterRememberMe();
    loginpage.eyeIcon();
    loginpage.forgotPasswordButton();
    loginpage.signUpButton();
    loginpage.clickSignIn();
    cy.wait(8000);
    cy.get('#company_name').type('Bilal Test');
    cy.get('.UploadFilestyles__UploadIcon-sc-xxr9kh-1').attachFile('Topics of Cypress.png');
    cy.get('#company_address').type('71 stationview place');
    cy.get('#primary_contact_person').type('Bilal');
    cy.get('#primary_contact_number').type('(342) 343-3423');
})
})
```

Always getting an error in the line

```js
cy.get('@signupData').then((signupData) => {
        const { email, password } = signupData;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write and read the variable to a fixture file:

**spec1.cy.js**

```js
it('test1', () => {
  const signupData = { email: 'fakeEmail', password: 'fakePassword' }
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/signupData.json', signupData)
})
```

**spec2.cy.js**

```js
it('test2', () => {
  cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/signupData.json').then(signupData => {
    expect(signupData).to.deep.eq({ email: 'fakeEmail', password: 'fakePassword' })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to store and preserve values across test files

https://github.com/optimumqa/cypress-store

### Installation

```bash
npm install @optimumqa/cypress-store
```

### Usage

#### Cypress version >= 10

```js
// ./cypress.config.js

import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

const finalConfig = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // Setup plugins
      config = import('@optimumqa/cypress-store')(on, config)

      return config
    },
  },
})
```

#### Cypress version < 10

```js
// ./cypress/plugins/index.js

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  config = require('@optimumqa/cypress-store')(on, config)

  return config
}
```

#### Usage

Below is an example saving a token inside one spec, and re-use it inside another.

You can have infinite stores.

Example of setting a new item into 'MyStoreForUsefulStuff'.

> If the store does not exist, it will be automatically created:

```js
// mySpec1.cy.js

cy.task('setItem', {
  storeId: 'MyStoreForUsefulStuff',
  item: {
    name: 'foo',
    value: 'bar',
  },
})
```

Example of getting an item from a store:

```js
// mySpec2.cy.js

cy.task('getItem', {
  storeId: 'MyStoreForUsefulStuff',
  item: {
    name: 'foo',
  },
}).then((item) => {
  console.log(item) // { name: 'token, value: 'foo' }
  console.log(item.name) // foo
  console.log(item.value) // bar
})
```